# Parsing SQLite with JSON, Client to Server

Tags: java, json, sqlite, server, client

I have got a GUI client, that can receive data from a multithreaded server. I then want to be able to send data back to the server. From what I understand with Json, I can use it to send the SQLite statement and also a string. I'm not sure if what I'm trying to implement is the best way forward, but this is what I have got. On the client:

```
private void addDriverToTable() {
    if (printWriter != null && bufferedReader != null) {

        String driverRef = driverRefTextField.getText();
        String driverNumber = numberTextField.getText();
        String driverCode = codeTextField.getText();
        String driverForename = forenameTextField.getText();
        String driverSurname = surnameTextField.getText();
        String driverDOB = dobTextField.getText();
        String driverNationality = nationalityTextField.getText();
        String driverURL = urlTextField.getText();

        System.out.println("get, " + driverRef + "," + driverNumber + "," + driverCode + "," + driverForename + ","
                + driverSurname + "," + driverDOB + "," + driverNationality + "," + driverURL);

        String insertDriver = "INSERT INTO drivers (driverRef, number, code, forename, surname, dob, nationality, url)" +
                "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        String addDriver = (driverRef + "," + driverNumber + "," + driverCode + "," + driverForename + "," +
                driverSurname + "," + driverDOB + "," + driverNationality + "," + driverURL);

        addDriverHashMap = new HashMap();
        addDriverHashMap.put(insertDriver, addDriver);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject addDriverData;
        addDriverData = gson.toJsonTree(addDriverHashMap).getAsJsonObject();

        System.out.println(addDriverData);

        String toSend = "add";
        printWriter.println(toSend);
        String toSendJson = String.valueOf(addDriverData);
        printWriter.println(toSendJson);

        String reply = null;

        printWriter.println(addDriverData);
        statusLabel.setText("Status: Adding Driver to database");
        try {
            reply = bufferedReader.readLine();
            statusLabel.setText("Status: Received reply from server");
        }catch (IOException ex){
            statusLabel.setText("IOException " + ex);
        }
        statusLabel.setText("Adding Driver to database");
    }else {
        statusLabel.setText("You must connect to the server first");
    }
}
```

On the client handler:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try{

        threadSays("Waiting for data from client...");
        String lineRead;
        while ((lineRead = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            threadSays("Read data from client: \"" + lineRead + "\".");

            if(command.matches("add")){
                if(command.matches("INSERT")) {
                    JsonObject jsonReply = JsonParser.parseString(arrayRead[0]).getAsJsonObject();
                    addMyDrivers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonReply));
                    insertDriver = (String) addMyDrivers.get(1);
                    addDriver = (String) addMyDrivers.get(2);
                    replyMessage = "Adding Driver to Database";
                    ThreadedServer.addDriver(insertDriver, addDriver);
                }
            }

            printWriter.println(replyMessage);

        }
    }catch (IOException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(ClientHandlerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally {
        try {
            threadSays("We have lost connection to client " + connectionNumber + ".");
            ThreadedServer.removeThread(this);
            socket.close();
        }catch (IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(ClientHandlerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally on the server:

```
public static void addDriver(String insertDriver, String addDriver) {
    try (Connection connection = ConnectionSQLite.getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertDriver)) {

            preparedStatement.setString(1, addDriver);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, addDriver);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, addDriver);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, addDriver);
            preparedStatement.setString(5, addDriver);
            preparedStatement.setString(6, addDriver);
            preparedStatement.setString(7, addDriver);
            preparedStatement.setString(8, addDriver);
            preparedStatement.execute();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SQLException.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

The SQLite message appears on the server, I can't work out how to actually get it to then do the insert, the data I'm trying to insert. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? Your `addDriver()` is called and the prepared statement is executed but the data is not in the database? Maybe in your database connection the auto commit property is turned off. If auto commit is disabled, then you have to explicitly commit after the insert.

Comment: Before I tried sending the data between client and server, I just sent it straight from the client to the database. This worked fine using the INSERT command, I just can't work out how to get it to be sent through the server. `ClientHandlerThread1: Read data from client: "{"INSERT INTO drivers (driverRef, number, code, forename, surname, dob, nationality, url)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)":"a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a"}"` I'm guessing that I need to remove { and also split the two strings. I'm just unsure on how to do it.

Comment: Um, of course it should be correct SQL. And you should split the parameter string and set each parameter individually. And why don't you send the full SQL string with parameters included as you would type it in a SQL client? Using a prepared statement does not increase security, if the SQL statement comes from the client anyway. In production, one would rather not allow the client to run SQL statements directly on the server.

Comment: On the server I'm using SQL statement to select all the drivers, then I have put the results into a HashMap and sent the data as Json. On the client I receive the reply and put the data into a table. My thinking was I could do something similar for adding data. The above is just the way I thought it should be done, I'm new to Java and working with servers. Are you suggesting that I use prepared statement on the client instead of the server?

Comment: Sorry, now I am a little confused. I thought you send the JSON to the server and try to execute the SQL statement there. But anyway, you should usually not send complete SQL statements over the wire and then execute this SQL. It is a great security risk. You should have a service layer which abstracts and hides the database layer. Only the data should be send back and forth according to your API. Internally you validate the data and use prepared statements to insert data into your database to reduce the risk of attacks.

Comment: I have probably confused myself as well. Is there any information I should look up in the future so I can understand how to get a server communicating with a client and also a SQLite database.

Comment: This is a wide topic. Maybe you should have a look into the [Oracle JEE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/) especially Part VI Webservices and the [Oracle Lesson: JDBC Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html). Sure, there are differences between relational databases. But they have a lot in common. That's why it's always good to know JDBC. So you can deal with all relational databases, not just SQLite.